Cannot change permission of azure app service linux directory
I have a WordPress blog hosted on Azure App Service Linux. I am unable to change either directories or files. Has anyone experienced the same issue? It has resulted in my blog being hacked multiple times.

I have root user.
change directory permission using
find . -type d -exec chmod 755 {} \;
and files using
find . -type f -exec chmod 644 {} \;

Is the app service using a container-based deployment?

No it is not, the app deployed using zip from azure devops cd

I'm going to take a guess here, but my hunch is that this is the issue (from this link):

When you persist storage with the WEBSITES_ENABLE_APP_SERVICE_STORAGE
app setting, we mount a location in Azure Storage to the /home mount
point. The permissions on this are 777. You cannot change these
permissions, even if you attempt to do so from an initialization
script or from SSH.

Be careful with this app setting.  If you set it to FALSE, the contents of the filesystem will be deleted after each restart.  See here for details.
Also, see this link

So, if I do not change the settings, is it safe, or is my app at risk?

What is the current value of the WEBSITES_ENABLE_APP_SERVICE_STORAGE app setting in your environment?

The WEBSITES_ENABLE_APP_SERVICE_STORAGE is not present; its default value should be true.

Given that it's true, we've established that the file permissions can't be changed for the reason I stated in my answer.   If you're wondering whether the 777 file permissions on a WordPress site hosted on Azure App Service cause a security risk, I'd suggest posting a new question.

I am also struggling with this question. I am having the same issue. Should I truly leave my permissions as 777 like OP? This seems like a huge problem unless there is some other technology in play keeping these deployments safe.
